# Django Ldap Settings

Tags: django, python-2.7, ldap

I am using Django LDAP authentication . By default we would give the LDAP settings in `settings.py` so that the `LdapBackend` file would access the `settings.py` file for the LDAP credentials . But in my case , i need the `LdapBackend.py` file to look into a separate json file for the LDAP settings . How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could [import json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) in your `settings.py` and [read the credentials from a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559).

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the json file and then read it in using the [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load) module.  json.load() will load the whole file at once and convert it to a python object.

```
import json
with open("filename.json") as json_file:
    ldap_stuff = json.load(json_file)
```